# How do you react if you’re a Druid and you’ve just calmed a hostile animal and your party member attacks it on their turn?

Tags: druid

I’m bad at RP and wanted to know how to handle the situation in the title, I mean obviously you can’t just attack your party member and I don’t really want to try to intimidate them so what would you do?

Comment: Hi Pawpals, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange. Kindly take the [tour]. This is a good question, but not really suited for our format - we actively try to avoid opinion-based questions, and how should one react is definitely opinion-based. You can find better help on the various RPG forums online, of which we have a curated list [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). Cheers!

Comment: It seems like this person isn't really asking for an opinion of what they should do, but rather is asking about a problem player who they believe is acting inappropriately.  Isn't that a more appropriate question?